# "Уполномочить" + винительный или родительный падеж?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, падежи, родительный-или-винительный

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой из падежей правильно употребить в данном случае - винительный или родительный:

Уполномочить Иванова И.И.

Понятно, что при написании не будет различия, но мы составляем форму документа и там нужно указать "ФИО в ***_***падеже" - запутались, какой должен быть. Лично я склоняюсь к родительному, т.к. форма винительного "что?" не может быть здесь использована логически - мы не можем уполномочить неодушевленный предмет, но коллеги считают иначе.

Спасайте! )

Comment: Спасибо! Пусть я оказалась неправа, но камень с души свалился наконец-то)))))

Answer (score 2):

Правы коллеги. Уполномочить президиум, комиссию и т. д. А по Вашей логике нельзя "уполномочить неодушевленный предмет", но можно "уполномочить неодушевленного предмета".

Answer (score 2):

Уполномочить(кого?) Иванова.Глагол  управляет В.п. , дело в том, что у ОДУШЕВЛЕННЫХ  существительных  Форма Р.п.= В.п. В.п. имеет два вопроса Что? и КОГО?
вижу что? поле
вижу кого? родственника, сравните р.п. нет  кого?  родственника.
 Поэтому  ФИО в винительном  падеже

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, винительный падеж. Можно и неодушевленный предмет уполномочить в художественном тексте. А в грамматике и подавно.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем так сложно? Поставьте на место Иванова даму. Тут-то уж падежи не перепутаешь.

Уполномочить Иванову. Уполномочить секретаршу. Уполномочить сестру... И никаких проблем с неодушевленностью.